# How i solve this rc4 encryption

Tags: python, encryption, rc4-cipher

```
def get_prg(plaintext_size, k):
    j = 0
    S = list(range(32))
    for i in range(32):
        j = (j + S[i] + ord(k[i % len(k)])) % 32
        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]
    return S


def fake_rc4(plaintext, keystream):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    i = (i + 1) % 32
    j = (j + keystream[i]) % 32
    keystream[i], keystream[j] = keystream[j], keystream[i]
    t = (keystream[i] + keystream[j]) % 32
    return t
```

i need at the end to return a cipher text.
at the `fake_rc4` I return the index of the keystream.
How at the other func do I encode the text using xor on the plain text?

I use mod 32 and not 256 because of an exercise.

this is the exercise:

> Write the stream cipher fake-RC4: implement a function encrypt that given a plaintext and a 32-bytes key  `k`, returns a ciphertext encrypted with a weak variant of RC4 which we describe here.
>
> First, implement the fake-RC4 pseudo-random generator (PRG):
>
> It starts with  `i = j = 0`, and to generate the next byte in the keystream it:
>
> - Increments  `i`  by  1 (modulo 32),
> - Increments  `j` by the  `i`th
>   character of the key (modulo 32),
> - Swaps the  `i`th
>   character of the key with its  `j`th character,
> - Adds the  `i`th
>   character of the key and its  `j`th
>   character, modulo `32`, and returns the key's character at that index.
>
> So for example, if the  `i`th
> character of the key was `'a'` (whose ASCII value is `97`), and its `j`th
> character was `'3'` (whose ASCII value is `51`), their sum would be `148`. Modulo the length of the key, the result will be  `148 % 32 = 20`, so the pseudo random generator would return the  `20`th
> character of the key as the next byte.
>
> Once you have the pseudo-random generator working, the rest is easy:
>
> - Iterate over the plaintext
> - XOR every character with the next byte of the pseudo-random generator's keystream
> - Return the result as the ciphertext!

Comment: What's the point of `i = (i + 1) % 32`? Since `i` is always `0`, that's just `i = 1`

Comment: Is there supposed to be a loop in `fake_rc4`?

Comment: What do you mean by "I return the index of the keystream"?

Comment: Why doesn't `fake_rc4()` use `plaintext`?

Comment: you mean like this?
`def fake_rc4(plaintext, keystream):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    S = []
    for char in plaintext:
        i = (i + 1) % 32
        j = (j + keystream[i]) % 32
        keystream[i], keystream[j] = keystream[j], keystream[i]
        t = (keystream[i] + keystream[j]) % 32
        S.append(keystream[t])
    return S`

Comment: `fake_rc4` needs to be a generator, or `i` and `j` need to be global variables so they retain their values between calls.